# How can I make a better ruined culture?

Tags: world-building

I don't want to make a cliche magic-heavy ancient empire destroyed by hubris. How can I make a more interesting one?

Comment: How would YOU destroy a magic empire?

Comment: Let's narrow this down.  What flavor and/or themes do you want to evoke in your game?  Is hubris inappropriate, or just something you're tired of seeing?  Should the things that destroyed the empire still be looming threats?

Comment: Which cliches do you want to remove: the "magic-heavy" part or the "ancient ruined empire" part?

Comment: Shouldn't we shunt these types of questions over to worldbuilding?

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith Only if it's off-topic here. People can ask here or there, per the expertise they're looking for. If they put it in the wrong place (because they're looking for expertise that's off topic on that site), then they get closed and we suggest they ask elsewhere.

Comment: For this to be relevant, we need to know what system you're planning to use. System impacts quite significantly here, as what is possible in system should be reflected in world, and vice versa.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton That's only true of some playstyles; i.e., "rules as physics" playstyles. It doesn't apply universally to all playstyles, so neither to all world-building questions.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest — and *standard* — way to subvert clichés is to look at the "atoms" of your cliché and then change one or more of them.

The atoms in your cliché are shown here with square brackets (nested for nested clichés):

> a [ [magic]-[heavy] ] [ancient] [empire] [ [destroyed] by [hubris] ]

Now pick one or more of those to swap out for something else, and you've instantly got a more interesting "one liner" for your imagination to start building from; e.g.:

- a magic-**light** ancient empire destroyed by **invaders**

Already, the mill is working on this grist. Magically-powerful invaders, perhaps? Perhaps they wanted to erase the old empire for full subjugation "high score", which gives you forgotten and lost ruins similar to the original cliché? Where it doesn't quite work, *those* are the places where you dig in and the answers create an intriguing, unique setting — for instance, how did they enforced forgetting, and why didn't they just destroy/build over the ruins? Maybe they did build over them, and *this* setting's forgotten ruins are all under major metropolises! And maybe the forgetting never happened, but the subjugated class lack access to education and so the old empire has become fantastical myths. Hearing of a new myth, and researching the construction history of the myth's location, becomes a typical adventuring hook and first act.

This kind of instant inspiration comes from any permutation you like. The more awkward ones actually lead to the most unique settings, as you fill in the cracks with the imaginative details that make it work.

- a magic-heavy **recent** empire destroyed by **natural disasters**
- a **spiritually-enlightened** ancient **land of self-ruled villages and free cities** destroyed by hubris

  (How does a distributed civilisation fall to *hubris*? Maybe a new religion, deliberately invented to unite the land, plunges it into sectarian war instead?)
- a magic-heavy ancient **city** destroyed by **hungry ghosts**
- a **technological** ancient empire **transformed** by **magic**
- a magic-heavy ancient empire destroyed by **technology**
- a magic-**outlawing** ancient empire **declining** **due to** **decadence**

And so on. Just coming up with replacements is fun, and fuels the imagination.

Comment: +1 for the interesting way to explore a simple sentence to find out new ideas. I definitely like this one.

Answer (score 3):

There are many things that can bring down an empire, or any civilization.  History is filled with examples: Rome, the Maya, the Aztecs, the Mongol empire, several Califates, the USSR, Khazaria, and many more.

### Magic, Technology & People

The empire being magical or not isn't a large factor.  Magic and technology are, at the societal level, similar instruments.  Magic and tech are both ways for people to leverage more power than they can unaided, creating the potential for wars, bureaucracies, and environmental impacts to all be more intense.  They also give people more tools to cope with problems like natural disasters.  For these reasons, magical and/or industrial societies can have *grander* problems and downfalls.

Hubris is a popular theme for the downfall of advanced societies because issues of hubris, moderation, and personal responsibility are magnified by technology or strong magic.  However, this magnification works for other problems, too, and your world's history needn't center on hubris.

### Many Intertwined Paths

In fiction, downfalls are often shown with a single, simple reason.  Sometimes this is because the story is meant as an allegory, and others it's because the story hinges upon the reason for the downfall.

In reality, and some fiction, the collapse of an empire is caused by the confluence of many factors.  A cataclysmic event might be remembered as the downfall, but that event usually requires many, sometimes unrelated, pieces pave the way first.

Common factors that can break down an empire:

- Natural disaster that inflicts massive casualties and destroys critical infrastructure
- Famine
- Civil unrest
- Being conquered
- Civil war
- Political coup and instability
- Economic collapse
- Toxic pollution

These factors are often interrelated.  A natural disaster can cause crop failure, which leads to both famine and economic collapse (like the Dust Bowl of the 1920s).

Famine and economic collapse can lead to civil unrest, provoking a popular revolt, or providing the opening for coup from within the existing government or ruling class.  If the revolution doesn't manage to transition quickly enough into a new, stable government the whole state can fall apart.

Civil wars break out when there are existing problems like inequality, poor (and unequal) standards of living, or strong ideological differences.

Losing a war clearly spells the end for a nation.  Winning one, or coming to a stalemate, can also be a problem if the war was expensive.  The empire spent so many resources and took so many casualties that, even in victory, they are weakened and dysfunctional.

### Picking your disasters

Whatever happened to your fictional empire, it will be a mystery or cautionary tale.  You don't see the aftermath of an epic fall without wanting to avoid it, or to understand what happened.

To build your world, think about what kinds of things the cautionary tale should warn about, and/or how you want the mystery to unfold.  Having parallels between the old empire's downfall and current problems in your story is often compelling.  Pick one or two major causes for the fall that can serve as a primary reason.

For Example Land, let's say the Wizard-Emperor, Korius the Great, was assassinated by a close adviser, General Len, plunging the kingdom into chaos.

### Supporting your disaster with multiple perspectives

History is said to be written by the victors.  Failing that, by the survivors.  The vanquished, the angry neighbors, and the people on the fringes are all going to have different ideas about what really happened.  If the civilization totally collapsed, then all you may have are second-hand stories and fragments.  You even have invented propaganda that the fallen's rivals created.

Within the same world, you might hear all of these stories given as reasons for the fall:

The people of Example Land lived out of harmony with the Gods and Spirits.  Their blasphemous ways led to their downfall as the Gods exacted punishment and the good Spirits abandoned them.

The aristocracy was decadent, and heedless of the people's needs.  Emperor Korius was the worst of them.  By the time he fell, it was too late to save the empire.  The petty greed of the nobles ruined all.

The Blue Pox brought them low.  Never shake hands with a stranger, or you could catch the Pox.

Emperor Korius was mad.  He slaughtered his own people by the hundreds and destroyed the empire.

The savage Hordes of Gor sacked the capitol, laying waste the splendor they didn't understand.  A bands of Gor still roam, but the glories of Example Land are long lost.

### What really happened?

Lots of things.  A kernel truth is in each story.  Generations of poor governance had already reduced Example Land's power from what it was in glory days.  Magic use disrupted the local environment, at first improving crop yields, but eventually reducing them.

Magical power was concentrated in the hands of aristocracy, and the growing wealth divide angered the people as resources grew more scarce.

When the Blue Pox came, a population already weakened by poor nutrition was very susceptible.  In a desperate attempt to stop the spread of Pox, Korius instituted harsh quarantine rules across cities and districts.  The civil unrest was growing, and the people of one town appeared on verge of breaking quarantine.  General Len was ordered to destroy the town with fire, to protect the capitol from the Pox.  Rather than slaughter civilians, he killed his king.

With the empire thus weakened, neighboring Gor nomad tribes plundered what was left, preventing any hope of rebuilding.

That's just one example.  You can pick and choose your disasters, and how you want to frame them in order to support the themes that are best for your story.

Answer (score 0):

Several causes can concur and make empires or civilization collapse. Here are a few one that could help you :

- **size** : communication is an issue when you have to maintain consistency in a big area. Real empires like the Roman or Mongol ones divided themselves to deal with this. In a fantasy world, magic may help to communicate.
- **resources** : empires usually take their resources from invaded or slave countries. If the latter rebel, or if no other life-space is available for plundering, they may find themselves in trouble. A real-life example is the Spanish domination of the new world : lots of gold an silver came from America, saturating the market and making this gold have less and less value. Meanwhile, Spain didn't bother about it's local economy, relying only on the New World gold.
- **invasion** : demographic pressure may push invaders again existing empires : Vikings for Medieval Europe, Germans for Roman Empire. Old empires are supposed to be wealthy and attract such invaders.
- **disease/famine** : population can be reduced by disease or other events. This may reduce communication and social relations locally and on a larger scope, shattering the unity of an empire. It is believed that romans were poisoned by the lead conduct they used widely.

Other causes may include : decay of infrastructures, excessive bureaucracy breaking adaptation to new situations, internal corruption, internal conflicts for personal power instead of common interest.

Fantasy causes may involve some magic going wrong, external creatures, pact with dark forces, gods wrath, a group of adventurers killing the ruler, etc.